# Why is the memory address 0x0 reserved, and for what?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, ram, memory-address

Why is the memory address 0x0 reserved, and for what? I am having trouble understanding for what exactly, thank you for helping

Answer (score 3):

It is mostly a *convention*, and it is implementation specific.

The C language standard (C99 or C11) -and some other programming languages such as Lisp- has the notion of [*null pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer) which cannot be dereferenced (that would be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)) and is different of any other pointer (to some valid memory location). Tony Hoare modestly called that notion ["my billion dollar mistake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare), and some languages (Haskell, Ocaml) have some [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) types (e.g. `'a option` in Ocaml) instead.

Most implementations (but not all) represent the null pointer by address 0.

In practice, on a desktop, laptop or tablet, a user-mode C program runs in some [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) where the page containing the address 0 is not mapped. (On some Linux, you perhaps could [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_FIXED` the address 0, but that would be poor taste...)

In some embedded [microcontrollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) (e.g. [AVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set)), address 0 could be used.

In theory (and in the past), addresses might be more complex than a number... (in the 1980s, e.g. [x86 memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) on [i286](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286), and [iAPX432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432) addressing, [Rekursiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekursiv) architecture, etc...)

Read several books and web pages on C programming, microprocessor architectures & [instruction sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) principles, [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)s.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a common practice on paged memory systems not to map the first (zeroth) page by default. This is a convention normally enforced by the linker. When the program loader reads the executable file, it never gets an instruction to map the first logical page.

The reason for this is to detect null pointer errors.

```
int *whatever = 0 ;
 . . . . 
*whatever = 10 ;
```

will cause an access violation.

That said, it is usually possible for a process to map the first (zeroth) page after execution starts and, in some cases, you can specify linker options allowing program sections to be based there.